# Remarkable articles about the distribution of prime numbers that were written by contemporary physicists

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I would like to ask about if you know papers containing remarkable achievements that were written by contemporary physicists concerning the distribution of prime numbers (or closely related, maybe the distribution of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function) in the spirit of the modern analytic number theory.

I am asking about it since I don't know how to search it, and I don't know how to know if a paper is remarkable for the community of professional mathematicians.

> **Question.** Can you as professional number theoretician or professor tell me  what are important and remarkable articles/papers due to contemporary physicists concerning the distribution of prime numbers in the spirit of the modern analytic number theory? Then add the references answering this question as a reference request. **Many thanks.**

Thus I assume that there are professors who, apart from studying their discipline in some field of physics or as a natural consequence of his/her investigations, provided relevant results in the study of the distribution of  prime numbers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102940/discussion-on-question-by-user142929-remarkable-articles-about-the-distribution).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would nominate Sir Michael Berry, FRS.  According to Wikipedia, "He is known for the Berry phase, a phenomenon observed e.g. in quantum mechanics and optics, as well as Berry connection and curvature. He specialises in semiclassical physics (asymptotic physics, quantum chaos), applied to wave phenomena in quantum mechanics and other areas such as optics."

His papers using tools of quantum chaos in analytic number theory include "The Riemann Zeros and Eigenvalue Asymptotics" (with J. Keating), SIAM REVIEW Vol. 41, No. 2, pp. 236–266, among others.

Comment: Many thanks now I am going to read the Wikipedia, and your answer. Many thanks again for your attention and patience.

Answer (score 8):

The [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery%27s_pair_correlation_conjecture) between the distribution of the Riemann zero's and the distribution of the eigenvalues of random unitary matrices was noted by the physicist [Freeman Dyson,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeman_Dyson) in a conversation with the mathematician [Hugh Montgomery.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Lowell_Montgomery) Here is a [this description](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/dyson.htm) of the conversation:

> Hugh Montgomery: "[Indian number theorist Daman Chowla] said, 'Have
>   you met Dyson?' and I said, 'No,' and he said, 'I'll take you and
>   introduce you to Dyson,' and I said 'No, no, that's OK, I don't need
>   to meet Dyson.' This went back and forth and it ended up with Chowla
>   dragging me across the room. I didn't really want to bother [Dyson]. I
>   didn't think of having anything useful to say to him, but when Chowla
>   introduced me Dyson was very cordial and asked me what I'd been
>   working on, and so I told him that I'd been looking at the zeros of
>   the zeta function."
>
> It was when Montgomery mentioned the formula he had found for this
>   distribution that Dyson's ears pricked up. At the mention of $1 - [(\sin
>  \pi u)/(\pi u)]^2$, Dyson said something like, 'Well, that's the density
>   of the pair correlation of eigenvalues of random matrices in the
>   Gaussian Unitary Ensemble.'
>
> "I'd never heard any of these terms before," Montgomery went on. "I
>   don't know exactly what his words were because I have heard all of
>   these terms many times since, but he said 'pair correlation' and
>   something resembling 'random matrices'..."
>
> "As far as I know," Montgomery said, "he didn't think about it after
>   this five-minute conversation. I haven't spoken with him since, so
>   I've had one conversation with him in my life. But it was quite a
>   fruitful conversation.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and links.

Comment: It should maybe be mentioned that besides being a physicist, Dyson is also very accomplished as a pure mathematician. At Cambridge, while he studied physics under Dirac, he also studied pure mathematics under Hardy and Besicovich.  He published quite a few papers in mathematics throughout his career.

Answer (score 6):

Marek Wolf, a Polish physicist, is the author of several articles about the distribution of prime numbers. He studied jumping champions and provided a heuristic formula refining Cramer's conjecture, and is also the author with Kourbatov, whose given name I forgot, of a paper about maximal prime gaps. Googling his name with such keywords should point to the relevant papers.

Comment: Many thanks, I don't know what are the most remarkable papers on primes of professor Marek Wolf.

Comment: Here comes his homepage: http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/

Comment: Alexei Kourbatov. "Predicting maximal gaps in sets of primes."  [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03785).

Comment: Alexei, da! Thank you for reminding me.